# How to create a reject regex expression

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am a beginner at regex. I want to write a regex expression for a list of reject characters. These characters include `^$\/()|?+*[]{}><`

Any help is appreciated.

Edit:
I want to test if any of those characters are present in a VB webform application.

```
Dim login As String
Dim password As String
Dim reject As String = "[$^\/()|?+*[]{}><]"
Dim rgx As New Regex(reject)
Dim matches As MatchCollection
Dim matches2 As MatchCollection
login = txtLogin.Text
password = txtPassword.Text
matches = rgx.Matches(login)
matches2 = rgx.Matches(password)
If matches.Count > 0 Then
    loginErr.Text = "Login can not contain ^ $ \ / ( ) | ? + * [ ] { } ><"
Else
    loginErr.Text = ""
End If
If matches2.Count > 0 Then
    passwordErr.Text = "Password can not contain ^ $ \ / ( ) | ? + * [ ] { } ><"
Else
    passwordErr.Text = ""
End If
```

Comment: You want to test to see if any of those characters are present?  Or you want the pattern to only match strings which do not contain any of those characters, or something else?

Comment: BTW, since there are many different flavors of regex, it's usually a good idea to specify which language, tool, or framework you are using to apply the pattern.  Though, admittedly, in this simple case, it probably won't matter.

Comment: Once you answer my first question, and fully define what it is you are looking for, the next thing I would suggest is that you show what you have tried, explain what about it is not working for you, and/or explain what is confusing you.  Usually, since this is a Q&A site, it's also a good idea to include a question of some kind.

Comment: Hi Steven, yes I want to test if any of those characters are present.

Comment: It's okay to restrict these characters from the username, but _really poor practice_ to restrict them from the password. It's a really awful thing to do from a security standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem that I see with your code is that you are not properly escaping the special characters `\`, `^`, and `]` in the character class:

```
Dim reject As String = "[$\^\\/()|?+*[\]{}><]"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Another question if you don't mind. How do I write a regex expression if I want to test for anything other than a-zA-Z0-9?

Comment: @Rascion you can negate a character class by prefacing it with a ^ character, for instance, [^a-zA-Z0-9]. However, simply using the predefined \W class may suit your needs.